# Azure security center enabling auto provision with ARM template does not work

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-security

I am trying to enable the auto provision for Azure security center with ARM template. My template has this as resource:

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/autoProvisioningSettings",
        "name": "default",
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
        "properties":{
            "autoProvision": "On"
        }
    }
```

However, this does not seem to work. I can use powershell to set it but I would like to have everything in ARM. Am I doing something wrong or how can I get the autoprovision set to on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template should be correct, I suppose it may be related to the way to deploy the template, I deploy it via the powershell, it works fine on my side.

**My complete template** `auto.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/autoProvisioningSettings",
            "name": "default",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "autoProvision": "On"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**My powershell to deploy the template**:

```
New-AzDeployment -Location "central us" -TemplateFile "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\auto.json"
```

**Test result**(note the change of the `autoProvision`):

[image]

Comment: For myself the powershell works as well but not template. Does the template work for you?

Comment: @Kamsiinov Yes, please note I just use the powershell to deploy the template, the template is the same with you, I do not use powershell to set it e.g. `Set-AzSecurityAutoProvisioningSetting -Name "default" -EnableAutoProvision` . They are different.

Comment: Ok, I did not understand it correctly first. Weird that my deployment with ARM is not working.

Comment: @Kamsiinov How did you deploy the template?1. If you deploy it in the custom template in the azure portal, you will get an error, because we should deploy it under the subscription not the resource group, in the portal, you could just deploy it under the resource group. 2. Also, you could not use `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`, it adds an Azure deployment to a resource group. You can try the `New-AzDeployment` as the same with my reply, it should work.

Comment: I am using similar powershell script than you.

Comment: It does not give any error. It just does everything else but the auto provision stays off.

Comment: @Kamsiinov Try to change the `$schema` to `https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#`. Theoretically speaking, it should use this one, but on my side,  both of them work, just have a try.

Comment: Thanks. Now I was able to get it working. I should have just try to use only the autoprovision since other parts seems to be breaking that.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the same template with latest version of az cli i.e. 2.0.60 on Mac
`command: az deployment create --location WestUS --template-file deploy.json`

and it worked. Verified by following command: 
`az security auto-provisioning-setting show -n "default"`

I think the Powershell module version in your host might not have the support for autoProvision property. UPGRADE Powershell module by following command :

`Update-Module -Name Az`

And, re-try the deployment by this powershell command:

`New-AzDeployment -Location "central us" -TemplateFile "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\auto.json"`

Comment: The point here is that with powershell it did work. It does not work with ARM template.

Comment: @Kamsiinov I am referring to the template deployment using powershell script command New-AzDeployment and not Set-AzSecurityAutoProvisioningSetting